# react input validation checking against last entered value instead of current value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to validate my input , if the number is between 100 and 200 is should display valid or invalid , the problem i'm having is that it seems to be checking against the last entered value, so for instance if the user enters 1222 this will display valid as I believe it is actually checking against the last entered number of 122 and also if I then delete 2 charachers so it displays 12 this will also display valid. I believe this is because of how the state is set but I am not sure how to correctly get this to work.

How can I change this so it will check against the correct value and validate correctly?

**Textbox.js**

```
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valid: '',
    value: ''
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
    this.validation()
  }

  validation() {
   (this.props.value > 100 && this.props.value < 200) ? this.setState({value: this.props.value}) : this.setState({value: this.props.value})
  }

  onChangeInput(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    }, () => console.log(this.state.mail === this.state.confMail));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Box
        invalid={!this.props.isValid}
      >
        <Label
          rollo={this.props.designation === 'rollo'}
          pleating={this.props.designation === 'pleating'}
        >{this.props.label}</Label>
          <span>
            <Input
              type={this.props.type && this.props.type}
              defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              value={this.props.value || ''}
            />
          <Tooltip>{this.state.valid}</Tooltip>
        </span>
      </Box>
    );
  }
};

export default TextBox;
```

**component.js**

```
<TextBox
  type="number"
  label="Fenstertyp"
  defaultValue={ this.props.height / 100 * 66 }
  onChange={newValue => this.props.selectOperationChainLength(newValue)}
  tooltip="invalid"
  value={this.props.operationChainLength.value}
/>
```

**actions.js**

```
export function selectOperationChainLength(operationChainLength) {
  return {
    type: SELECT_OPERATION_CHAIN_LENGTH,
    operationChainLength
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `validation` function seems weird as told on of the answers. Either the condition is true or false, you are setting the state as the same value. Also, I don't get what changes your `valid` state. Will `validation` do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift the validation logic to onChange method on event.target.value, there is no need to create the separate method. It will then look like this.

```js
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valid: false,
    value: ''
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    (value > 100 && value < 200) ? this.setState({value, valid: true}) : this.setState({value, valid: false})
    this.props.onChange(value);
  }

  onChangeInput(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    }, () => console.log(this.state.mail === this.state.confMail));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Box
        invalid={!this.props.isValid}
      >
        <Label
          rollo={this.props.designation === 'rollo'}
          pleating={this.props.designation === 'pleating'}
        >{this.props.label}</Label>
          <span>
            <Input
              type={this.props.type && this.props.type}
              defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              value={this.props.value || ''}
            />
          <Tooltip>{this.state.valid}</Tooltip>
        </span>
      </Box>
    );
  }
};

export default TextBox;
```

Comment: thanks that works great , I'm trying to work out what the difference between this and                                                                                                             
 `onChange = (event) => {
    this.validation(event)
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
 }

  validation(event) {
   (event.target.value > 100 && event.target.value < 200) ? this.setState({value: true}) : this.setState({value: false})
  }` is

Comment: First of all you should only pass what is required in the function so instead of passing event you can pass event.target.value. Secondly the major difference I see is you have updated value instead of valid in state. Besides these everything is logically similar.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so there are some things going wrong here.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class TextBox extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // 1.
    // You only need to store the `isValid` property.
    // The value is needed only for the validation, right?
    this.state = {
      isValid: false
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    const { target } = e;
    const { value } = target;
    // 2.
    // If the value is in the right range : isValid = true
    // else : isValid = false
    if( value > 100 && value < 200 ) {
      this.setState({ isValid: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isValid: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    // 3. 
    // Always use destructuring. It's way easier to follow ;)
    const { type } = this.props;
    const { isValid } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input 
          type={type}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} 
        />
        {/* 4. */}
        {/* Assign the right text to your tooltip */}
        <p>{ isValid ? "valid" : "invalid" }</p>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TextBox type="number" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
<div id="root"></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I simplified the example so it can be easier to follow.

[Here is a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxmgGK)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your valid as false to begin with

```
state = {
valid: false,
value: ''
}
```

Comment: if I change my state to `valid: false` and `  (this.props.value > 100 && this.props.value < 200) ? this.setState({value: this.props.value}) : this.setState({value: !this.props.value})` the validation doens't change from false to true at all

Comment: yea you would need to set valid to true when your conditions meet. in your case

Comment: if( value > 100 && value < 200 ) {
               this.setState({ isValid: true });